# How to monitor a specific interface with mtr

Tags: networking, monitoring, mtr

So, I have two interfaces from different ISP's and I'm trying to monitor my connection using `mtr`. 
This is the command I'm currently trying to use:

```
mtr --no-dns --address $MY_REAL_IP_HERE $A_DESTINATION_IP
```

Unfortunately this is not going though the interface I want it to. At the moment I have `eth1` and `ppp0`, and I would like to monitor only `ppp0`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the command above is perfectly correct. Unfortunately at the time I asked the question the routing table was a bit broken. So the actual route was going though the wrong IP address even with the `--address` argument.